# Extract hex number from string python

Tags: python, string, hex, extract

I'm trying to extract hex number from this string (type str) :

```
mystring = b'\r\n+CUSD: 2,"062506460642063706270639002006270644062E062F06450629002006230639062F0020062706440625062A063506270644",72\r\n\r\nOK\r\n'
```

I tried:

```
hexnumber= m = re.findall(r'[0-9a-fA-F]+' , mystring)
print(hexnumber)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'C', 'D', '1', '0637064406280020063A064A0631002006450648062C0648062F000A002D0020002D0020002D000A00300030003A0627064406420627062606450629000A0030003A0631062C06480639', '72']
```

The output i'm looking for is :

```
0637064406280020063A064A0631002006450648062C0648062F000A002D0020002D0020002D000A00300030003A0627064406420627062606450629000A0030003A0631062C06480639
```

Comment: What makes "b", "C", "2" parts invalid?  Is it because they are too short?  Or is it because they are not surrounded by double quotes?  You need to come up with a more precise pattern that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "string" is not a string with actually **bytes** (`b'…'`), so you should probably decode according to the used encoding (I assumed utf-8 here).

Then I also assumed you want to extract the string in between quotes, so I suggest using a regex with lookarounds:

```
import re
out = re.findall(r'(?<=")[a-fA-F\d]+(?=")', mystring.decode('utf-8'))
if out:
    print(out[0])

# 062506460642063706270639002006270644062E062F06450629002006230639062F0020062706440625062A063506270644
```

You can also set a minimum number of characters in your pattern (here 8 or more):

```
re.findall(r'[a-fA-F\d]{8,}', mystring.decode('utf-8'))
```